# Can I trust companies that test antimalware software?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, antimalware, malware-analysis

Do they lie? I mean companies something like AV-TEST, AV-Comparatives, Virus Bulleting, ERG Effitas, etc.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is undefined. Do they ALL lie? Of course not. But we can't provide service reviews just as we can't provide product reviews.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "trust". If you mean "Everything they say is an objective, infallible truth", then **no**, you can't.

If you mean "Their tests are reasonable and give a reasonable comparison between competing products, then the answer is **maybe**. Without knowing all specifics, it's difficult to tell which conscious and unconscious biases affect their results.

For example, the simple act of weighing how much a given feature affects the overall score will affect the result one way or another. This could be done consciously to favor one product over the other, while seemingly remaining neutral. Or it can be done by sheer happenstance.